# Integral for infinitely small interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, definite-integrals, real-numbers

I was thinking about integration by parts on small interval, $[a, a + dx]$ when $dx \to 0.$ More precisely, suppose $f(x) = f, g(x) = g$ are both differentiable. I wanted to prove directly that

$$f(a + dx)g(a + dx) - f(a)g(a) \tag{*} $$

is equal to $\int_{a}^{a + dx} g \, df + \int_{a}^{a + dx} f \, dg $ (this is formula for IBP).

Indeed, we can simply write $f(a + dx) - f(a) = df$ and similarly $g(a + dx) - g(a) = dg.$

Now we have that (*) is $(f(a) + df)(g(a) + dg) - f(a)g(a) = f(a)dg + g(a)df + dfdg.$

We can intuitively exclude $dfdg$ from calculation (as product rule tells us).

And now, **the crushing part**: if $\int_{a}^{a + dx}g\,df$ is equal to $gdf$ (and of course same for other integral) we are done. Let me explain: we can treate $df$ as some fixed value, so we want to prove $$df \cdot \int_{a}^{a + dx}g = g(a)df.$$

This looks very weird. Interval is getting smaller and smaller but we can always find input $x := \frac{2a + dx}{2}$ (midpoint of $[a, a + dx]$) and corresponding output $g(\frac{2a + dx}{2})$ (and midpoints of that two subintervals, etc.) Therefore, sum of $g$-values is always (much) greater than $g(a)$ because there is $\infty$ many $g$ values for inputs between $a, a + dx.$

My intuition tells me that this is because somehow $dx < c, \forall c \in \mathbb{R},$ but that doesn't seem right.

In short: how is possible (if is) that for real function defined on interval $[a, a + dx]$ is $\int_{a}^{a + dx}f(x) = f(a)$?

Comment: You are tricking yourself with the notation. Intuitively, the integral symbol sums differentials  over small subintervals of the given domain of integration. In this regard, you should really regard $$\int_{a}^{a + dx}g\,df\approx g(a)\,df$$

Comment: I don't understand. Definite integral is the limit of a sum, but here sum has infinitely many terms of g(a)'s (approximately) and how is this equal to g(a)?

Comment: I found some logic... $\int_{a}^{a + dx} f'(x)\,dx = f(a + dx) - f(a)$ and thus $\int_{a}^{a + dx} = \frac{f(a + dx) - f(a)}{dx} = f'(a).$

Comment: No, I am wrong. This trick works **only** because I explicitly treat interval $[a, a + dx]$ as width of exatcly 1 rectangle. Then if we take for example $f(x) = 1$ is $\int_{a}^{a + dx} f(x)\,dx = dx,$ not $\infty,$ of course.

Comment: If $\Delta x$ is sufficiently small and $f$, $g$ are nice (for instance, $g$ is of class $C^0$ and $f$ is of class $C^1$), then $$ \int_{a}^{a+\Delta x}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}f(x)=g(a)(f(a+\Delta x)-f(a))+o(\Delta x), $$ and so, we may loosely claim that $$  \int_{a}^{a+\Delta x}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x) \approx g(a) \Delta f.$$ This is essentially because, if $\Delta x$ is small, then $g$ would behave almost like a constant function on $[a,a+\Delta x]$ with the value $g(a)$, and so,$$\int_{a}^{a+\Delta x}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}f(x)\approx\int_{a}^{a+\Delta x}g(a)\,\mathrm{d}f(x)=g(a)(f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)).$$